# Geometric progression first term and common ratio of progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio

[image: geometrix progression]

Do I simplify? Trying to find first term and common ratio of the progression aswell as the sum of all the terms in the progression for homework please help trying to know what I’m doing wrong so I can move on

Comment: Nooo, the notation means that $n$ varies from 1 to 10, not that the parenthetical expression is raised to the tenth power.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's something that helped me a lot when I first came here and was trying to learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  If you right-click on any formula, and then choose "Show Math As ... TeX Commands" from the pop-up, you get another pop-up that shows you the MathJax.  That way, you can see how the formula was formatted, or copy and paste it into your own post.  (Just be sure to put `$` signs around it.)

Answer (score 2):

What does the notation $(3*2^{n-1})_{n=1}^{10}$ mean?

A geometric progression in general is usualy given 
 as a sequence $a_{k}$ which satisfies $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a{k}}=constant$
which can be written as $a_{k+1}=a_{k}c\ \text{where c is the constant ratio}$.

If you start at given $a_{0}$ and with given constant c then the
kth value calculates as $a_{0}c^{k-1}$.

So you want to calculate the first 10 elements(terms) for $a_{0}=3$
and $c=2$ ???

The first value of the geometric progression $3*2^n$ if n starts at 0 (or
$3*2^{n-1}$ if n starts at 1) should be $3$,the second $2*3=6$,the 10th
$3*2^9=3*64=192$ and so on..

The sum of your progression up to 10 calculates as
$$3*\sum_{n=1}^{10}2^{n-1}=3*\frac{2^{10}-1}{2-1}=3*(2^{10}-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

$(3\cdot 2^{n-1})_{n=1}^{10}$ gives:

$3\cdot 2^{1-1}, 3\cdot 2^{2-1},\dotso, 3\cdot 2^{10-1}$

So let $a_n=3\cdot 2^{n-1}$. You are now asked to find $q$ such that $q\cdot a_n = a_{n+1}$

Comment: Where is the q from little explanation please so I don’t  make same mistake again. So the common ratio is 1?

Comment: To get the $q$ you might write down $a_1, a_2$ and so on. Now ask yourself which factor you need, to get from $a_1$ to $a_2$ by multiplication. Also you can just calculate $a_2  / a_1$.